# Php-Image function returns false?

Tags: php, image, file, function, rights

Hey there i have this snippet:

```
$profile_pic = imagecreatefromjpeg("upload_Main/".$user[1].".jpg");
```

This function works (upload_Main: folder:777 ; files:644)

But this snippet:

```
$profile_pic = imagecreatefromjpeg("upload_Sub/".$user[1].".jpg");
```

Doesnt work (upload_Sub: folder:777 ; files:644).

They have exactly the same files and the same right´s, so why does the second one not work? Any idea´s? thanks and greetings!

Comment: Check your error logs/activate error reporting, it should show something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[imagecreatefromjpeg():](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php)

```
Returns an image resource identifier on success, FALSE on errors.
```

I had it return False on an image that was manually re-named to a JPG, when it was actually a PNG.
I got an error saying:

```
'not a valid JPEG file'
```

You should look to see what error you get when performing that function, That way you'll know exactly what's goind bad.

One way to check for the error is creating a PHP file next to the image with:

```
<?php
  echo imagecreatefromjpeg("path/to/image");
?>
```

run it in using 'php filename.php'
and looking in the console for the result

Comment: on my server i just allow uploading png and jpeg/jpg, so before i do this function, i have to check if its a png or jpeg yea?

Comment: It depends on the error you get. You still havn't showed it